# Phonegap + Sencha touch 2 + Android first ajax request opens the browser

Tags: android, ajax, cordova, sencha-touch-2

I have an Sencha Touch 2 application and I'm using PhoneGap (Cordova) to get it to work as an native application.

I got plenty of Ext.Ajax requests in my application and they work fine on iOS (with XCode). But when I launch the application to my Android device thru Eclipse the first executed Ext.Ajax request seems to start and open the ordinary browser with a blank page open. The request still runs and works inside the application at the same time. 
The upcoming requests do not do this, and I can close the ordinary browser, go back and run the same request that opened the browser the first time and it will not do it again, until I re-launch my application.

I've tried to search for a solution for this issue but I have not found anything helpful yet, does any one got any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: your issue is probably with phonegap, you can remove sencha from the equation since sencha has no current funcitonality to open in browser from an installed app